# What is this evergreen plant and how should I care for it?

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-care, evergreens

I bought this plant from a local nursery, and the owner was ignorant about the plant details...

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I hope this isn't too general, but it looks like a juniper of some kind. It also doesn't look like a houseplant.